# Changing Nav Bar title programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to change my nav bar's title programmatically but the code I'm using won't work.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.navigationController.navigationItem.title=@"Hello";
```

I can manage to change the colour of the bar but not the text.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"YourTitle";
```

Comment: This bit of code works the exact same as Mudit's but it's shorter. Just place it in viewWillAppear and it's perfect

Comment: I have both navbar and tabbar and when i was trying to edit nav title programatically either with self.navigationItem.title or self.navigationcontroller.title or self.title, it was changing values in both navbar title and first tab on tabbar. This line does change only nav bar.Just for future reference for people who have same problems :)

Answer (score 27):

or `self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";`

Answer (score 12):

First check the index of  current controller on the navigation stack through

```
 NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController.viewControllers );
```

after finding the index of  current ViewController let say 1.

```
UINavigationController *navCon  = (UINavigationController*) [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    navCon.navigationItem.title = @"Hello";
```

Comment: Thanks, That managed to set the title for the nav bar, but rather than setting the title for just the one page, I'd like it to have a different title for each tab. I've tried using the above fix on two different tabs, but whatever tab I click last, changes the nav bar title to that permanently. So even if I load my other tab, the title doesn't change. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: in viewWillAppear  of that controller you can apply the same process.

Comment: I m not genious,actually i have faced the same problem in my previous project,that's y i have d solution...

Comment: I am getting null for this

Answer (score 7):

You can use built in method **setTitle** now in XCode
 `[self setTitle:@"title"]` 
or 
 `self.title=@"title"` 
inside its viewController.

Comment: ah aththada :D maru ahh

Answer (score 1):

For swift 2.2

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Superman title"
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with this :

```
[navigationController setTitle:@"Title"];
```

Comment: Not a great example as `navigationController` is probably an instance variable that is not being shared here.